# Isomorphism between two groups involving direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, is it true that $(H \times H) / (N \times N)$ is always isomorphic to $(H / N) \times (H / N)$ where $\times$ is the direct product?

Seems like it is to me. Consider the map

\begin{equation}
\phi : (H \times H) / (N \times N) \rightarrow (H / N) \times (H / N)
\end{equation}

defined by $\phi((a,b)(N \times N)) = aN \times bN$. This map is clearly surjective. It is injective because if $aN \times bN = cN \times dN$, then $a^{-1}c \in N$ and $b^{-1}d \in N$ and hence $(a,b)(N \times N) = (c,d)(N \times N)$. It can also be checked that it is a well-defined homomorphism.

Comment: $aN\times bN$ should be $(aN,bN)$ when define $\phi$. And yes, the isomorphism is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but the common way to do it would be to consider first the map $\phi: H\times H\to (H/N)\times(H/N)$ mapping $(a,b)\mapsto(aN,bN)$. In this case, it is clear that we are dealing with a surjective group homomorphism. We have $\phi(a,b)=1=(N,N)$ if and only if $aN=N$ and $bN=N$, which is equivalent to $(a,b)\in N\times N$. Hence, $\ker(\phi)=N\times N$ and the universal property of the quotient implies your isomorphism. This line of argument saves you a lot of effort but yields the exact same isomorphism.